# How to secure the source code of react native application?

Tags: javascript, react-native, security, expo, obfuscation

I am building an application that has auth system and a lot of post requests,

I want to know how to make my backend endpoints accept only requests that are coming from my application, not from anything else like Postman.

For example, if a user submitted a registration form, a post request is sent to my backend with user info, how can I make sure this post request is coming from my application?

What I was thinking of, is saving a secret on the client’s side that is to be sent with each request to the backend, so that I can make sure the request is coming from my app.
I think SSL pinning is meant for this.

I know that anyone can access my app source code if they extract the APK file.
I want to make sure that no one can alter or steal my source code.

I read that I can make my code unreadable by Obfuscating it ( I still need to figure out how I am going to do that on my EAS build ), is this enough?

And I have to use JailMonkey to detect if the device is rooted.

I am using Expo secure store to save my sensitive info on the client side.

Is this approach good enough, is there anything I am missing?
I have zero information about security, this is just what I learned through searching.

Let me know if you have better suggestions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See OWASP Cheat Sheet Series [Cross-Site Request Forgery Prevention](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html). You might also search SO for React + CSRF as there are many similar question.s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Difference Between WHO and WHAT is Accessing the API Server

> I want to know how to make my backend endpoints accept only requests that are coming from my application, not from anything else like Postman.

First, you need to understand the difference between **WHO** and **WHAT** is accessing the API Server to be in a better position to look for a solution to your problem.

I wrote a series of articles around API and Mobile security, and in the article [Why Does Your Mobile App Need An Api Key?](https://blog.approov.io/why-does-your-mobile-app-need-an-api-key#api-who-vs-what) you can read in detail the difference between **who** and **what** is accessing your API server, but I will extract here the main takes from it:

> The **what** is the thing making the request to the API server. Is it really a genuine instance of your mobile app, or is it a bot, an automated script or an attacker manually poking around your API server with a tool like Postman?

> The **who** is the user of the mobile app that we can authenticate, authorize and identify in several ways, like using OpenID Connect or OAUTH2 flows.

So think about the **who** as the user your API server will be able to Authenticate and Authorize access to the data, and think about the **what** as the software making that request in behalf of the user.

When you grasp this idea and it's ingrained in your mindset, then you will look into mobile API security with another perspective and be able to see attack surfaces that you never though they existed before.

### Certificate Pinning and MitM Atacks

> What I was thinking of, is saving a secret on the client’s side that is to be sent with each request to the backend, so that I can make sure the request is coming from my app. I think SSL pinning is meant for this.

Certificate pinning on the mobile app side serves to guarantee that the app is talking only with your API server and not anything else, like when a MitM attack occurs and the app has its requests intercepted, and potentially modified and/or replayed, or simply saved to later extract the secrets from it.

Pinning doesn't guarantee to your API server that the request is coming indeed from **what** it expects, a genuine and unmodified version of your mobile app, "unless" you implement mutual pinning, that isn't encouraged to do so, because you will need to ship the private key for the API server certificate in the mobile app. Even if you do so, all an attacker needs to do is to extract the private key and will be able to communicate with your API server like if it was your genuine mobile app.

I don't have an article to implement pinning on a react-native mobile app but you can take a look to the one I wrote for Android to understand better all the process. Read my article [Securing HTTPS with Certificate Pinning on Android](https://blog.approov.io/securing-https-with-certificate-pinning-on-android) on how you can implement certificate pinning and by the end you will understand how it can prevent a MitM attack.

> In this article you have learned that certificate pinning is the act of associating a domain name with their expected X.509 certificate, and that this is necessary to protect trust based assumptions in the certificate chain. Mistakenly issued or compromised certificates are a threat, and it is also necessary to protect the mobile app against their use in hostile environments like public wifis, or against DNS Hijacking attacks.

> You also learned that certificate pinning should be used anytime you deal with Personal Identifiable Information or any other sensitive data, otherwise the communication channel between the mobile app and the API server can be inspected, modified or redirected by an attacker.

> Finally you learned how to prevent MitM attacks with the implementation of certificate pinning in an Android app that makes use of a network security config file for modern Android devices, and later by using TrustKit package which supports certificate pinning for both modern and old devices.

### Bypassing Certificate Pinning

> I think SSL pinning is meant for this.

The good news is that you already learned how good pinning is to prevent MitM attacks, now the bad news is that it can be bypassed, and yes I also wrote an article on how to it on Android (sorry to not be specific on react-native). If you want to learn the mechanics of it then read my article [How to Bypass Certificate Pinning with Frida on an Android App](https://blog.approov.io/how-to-bypass-certificate-pinning-with-frida-on-an-android-app):

> Today I will show how to use the Frida instrumentation framework to hook into the mobile app at runtime and instrument the code in order to perform a successful MitM attack even when the mobile app has implemented certificate pinning.

> Bypassing certificate pinning is not too hard, just a little laborious, and allows an attacker to understand in detail how a mobile app communicates with its API, and then use that same knowledge to automate attacks or build other services around it.

### Code Obfuscation and Modifying Code

> I know that anyone can access my app source code if they extract the APK file. I want to make sure that no one can alter or steal my source code.
> Sorry, but once you release it to the public is up for grabs for everyone, even if heavily obfuscated its still possible to modify it statically or during runtime.

> I read that I can make my code unreadable by Obfuscating it ( I still need to figure out how I am going to do that on my EAS build ), is this enough?

No, you can use the best obfuscation tool, but then an attacker well versed in deobuscation techniques will be able to understand your code and modify it statically or at runtime. Several open-source tools exist to ake this easy, and if you read the article to bypass certificate pinning then you already saw an example of doing it at runtime with [Frida](https://www.frida.re/):

> Inject your own scripts into black box processes. Hook any function, spy on crypto APIs or trace private application code, no source code needed. Edit, hit save, and instantly see the results. All without compilation steps or program restarts.

### RASP - Runtime Application Self-Protection

> And I have to use JailMonkey to detect if the device is rooted.

Using Frida the check can be modified to always return that the device is not rooted. Also JailMonkey may not detect all ways used to hide that a device is rooted, and this a moving target, because hackers and developers are in a constant cat and mouse game.

### Sensitive Info Security

> I am using Expo secure store to save my sensitive info on the client side.

Even when a secret is securely stored it will need to be used at some point, and the attacker will hook Frida to this point and extract the secret or do it in a MitM attack.

### Possible Solutions

> Is this approach good enough, is there anything I am missing?

From all I wrote it looks no matter what you are doomed to failure in properly secure your sensitive info and to guarantee that your API server knows that **what** is making the request is the genuine mobile app it expects, but security its all about of applying as many layers of defences as possible, like done in medieval castles, prisons, etc., because this will increase the level of effort, time and expertise required to succeed in an attack.

You now need to find a solution that allows you to detect MitM attacks, tampered and modified apk binaries, Frida present at runtime and that can deliver a runtime secret to mobile apps that pass a mobile app attestation that guarantees with a very high degree of confidence that such threats are not present. Unfortunately I don't know any open-source project that can deliver all this features, but a commercial solution exists (I work there), and if you want to learn more about you can read the article:

[Hands-on Mobile App and API Security - Runtime Secrets Protection](https://approov.io/blog/hands-on-mobile-app-and-api-security-runtime-secrets-protection)

> In a previous article we saw how to protect API keys by using Mobile App Attestation and delegating the API requests to a Proxy. This blog post will cover the situation where you can’t delegate the API requests to the Proxy, but where you want to remove the API keys (secrets) from being hard-coded in your mobile app to mitigate against the use of static binary analysis and/or runtime instrumentation techniques to extract those secrets.
>
> We will show how to have your secrets dynamically delivered to genuine and unmodified versions of your mobile app, that are not under attack, by using Mobile App Attestation to secure the just-in-time runtime secret delivery. We will demonstrate how to achieve this with the same Astropiks mobile app from the previous article. The app uses NASA's picture of the day API to retrieve images and descriptions, which requires a registered API key that will be initially hard-coded into the app.

### Do You Want To Go The Extra Mile?

In any response to a security question I always like to reference the excellent work from the OWASP foundation.

#### For APIS

[OWASP API Security Top 10](https://github.com/OWASP/API-Security)

> The OWASP API Security Project seeks to provide value to software developers and security assessors by underscoring the potential risks in insecure APIs, and illustrating how these risks may be mitigated. In order to facilitate this goal, the OWASP API Security Project will create and maintain a Top 10 API Security Risks document, as well as a documentation portal for best practices when creating or assessing APIs.

#### For Mobile Apps

[OWASP Mobile Security Project - Top 10 risks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Mobile_Security_Project#Top_Ten_Mobile_Risks)

> The OWASP Mobile Security Project is a centralized resource intended to give developers and security teams the resources they need to build and maintain secure mobile applications. Through the project, our goal is to classify mobile security risks and provide developmental controls to reduce their impact or likelihood of exploitation.

[OWASP - Mobile Security Testing Guide](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-mstg):

> The Mobile Security Testing Guide (MSTG) is a comprehensive manual for mobile app security development, testing and reverse engineering.

Comment: This helped me a lot, I can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 1):

short answer you can't.

> I want to know how to make my backend endpoints accept only requests
> that are coming from my application, not from anything else like
> Postman

the only thing you can do here is cors Cross-Site Request Forgery Prevention. Y to stop other servers from calling your api.
and you can't make only your application communicate with the server
you can hard code(parameters in the request) in the application to send to the server.but hackers can listen to request made from devices

> I know that anyone can access my app source code if they extract the
> APK file. I want to make sure that no one can alter or steal my source
> code.

short answer you also can't

you can use ProGuard(native code) to obfuscate on native android and ios have compiled binary on release but those are not to js

so basically anyone can read your bundle js in plain text editor.
maybe in the future facebook can make something for hermes.

Comment: Can a hacker access data saved in variables inside my source code while the app is running?
and doesn't SSL pinning is a good way to identify the app that is sending data to my server?

Comment: here they discuss it ->https://reactnative.dev/docs/security

Comment: Up vote because the only possible answer to a naïve question like this one is "you can't".